# WPF Custom control dependency property: cannot be string type?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to add a `DependencyProperty` to a WPF custom control.

Everything is fine until I keep the code generate by the snippet propdp:

```
namespace CustomControl
{

    public partial class MainControl
    {
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MainControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

        public MainControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

But as soon as I change the type from "int" to "string", I got a runtime error which tells
"Impossible to create an instance of MainControl defined in assembly CustomControl etc....

Then I change back to type "int" and everything run again properly.

Does somebody have a clue to fix this mystery?

Comment: Are you sure youhave posted the code that causes the error? That dependency property compiles for me. Have you missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(0)
```

You're saying that the property has a type of `string`, but its default value is the `int` 0. Either change that to some string value that you want as a default (`null`, `string.Empty`, or something else), or remove that parameter completely – it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the default value to `null`, not `0` which is an invalid value for string:

```
new UIPropertyMetadata(null)
```

(Or whatever string value you want to be the default value.)